# How: JSON image URL display as actual image

Tags: javascript, json

My JS code below grabs JSON objects and prints them on a webpage, but only the text.  I.E. This prints the image URL (actual text) vs. displaying the actual image.  How can I change up the code below... add img src= somewhere in the code to show the actual image on the page?

```js
 function onShowtimesLoaded(data){
   var movieArray = data.results[0].movie;
   movieArray.forEach(function(el, index) {
    
          var elm = document.createElement('div');
          elm.setAttribute('id','movie_'+parseInt(index+1));
          elm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Movie Title: " + el.movieTitle));
          elm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Movie Poster: " + el.poster));
          elm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Movie Show Times: " ));
          var showtimes = el.showtimes.forEach(function(element, index) {
     elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("  "+element.time+"  "));
    });
    document.getElementById("MovieContainer").appendChild(elm);
   });
    }
 function callAPI() {
  var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;
     (function(){
             //note the "onShowtimesLoaded" at the end
             var src = 'closesttheater-'+pincode+'.json?format=json&callback=onShowtimesLoaded';
             script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
             script.src = src;
             document.head.appendChild(script);
     })();
    }
```

Comment: Be warned, there is a question ban. If you keep [deleting questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723093/javascript-how-to-print-json-datas-images-in-html) and [re-posting them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723765/javascript-how-to-display-json-image-url-as-image-in-html), you will eventually hit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds about right?

```
<script>
function onShowtimesLoaded(data){
            var movieArray = data.results[0].movie;
            movieArray.forEach(function(el, index) {

                var elm = document.createElement('div');
                elm.setAttribute('id','movie_'+parseInt(index+1));
                elm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Movie Title: " + el.movieTitle));
                elm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                var tmp_img = document.createElement('img');
                tmp_img.src = el.poster;
                elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Movie Poster: " ));
                elm.appendChild(tmp_img);
                elm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Movie Show Times: " ));
                var showtimes = el.showtimes.forEach(function(element, index) {
                    elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode("  "+element.time+"  "));
                });
                document.getElementById("MovieContainer").appendChild(elm);
            });
    }
    function callAPI() {
        var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;
        (function(){
                //note the "onShowtimesLoaded" at the end
                var src = 'closesttheater-'+pincode+'.json?format=json&callback=onShowtimesLoaded';
                script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
                script.src = src;
                document.head.appendChild(script);
        })();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Great, that did it!  Im now trying to figure out how to style the movie title by adding a h1 somehow.  I tried a similar way to how you added the img tag, but no luck there.  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: var tmp_title = document.createElement('h1');
                tmp_title.innerHTML = el.movieTitle;
elm.appendChild(tmp_title);